# Jena delete a triple with an anonymous node

Tags: rdf, jena, blank-nodes

I have been trying to delete a triple from a model using Jena with no success. Things work well when the subject, predicate and object are URIs or literals, but for anonymous nodes it doesn't seem to work.  For example, consider this triple in a model:

```
_:A68d23cacX3aX13f793fa898X3aXX2dX7ffd <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#value> "class" .
```

I would like to delete it using:

```java
Node nodeSubject = Node.createAnon(); //or Node.ANY
Node nodePredicate = Node.createURI("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#value");
Node nodeObject = Node.createLiteral("class");
Triple triple = Triple.create(nodeSubject, nodePredicate,  nodeObject);
inMemModel.getGraph().delete(triple);
```

I can't delete the triple regardless if I use `createAnon` or `Node.ANY`.
I wouldn't want to use a AnonId just cause if I run my code on another machine I doubt that the same anonymous id will be generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer:

```java
inMemModel.removeAll(null, RDF.value, ResourceFactory.createPlainLiteral("class"));
```

That will remove all triples where the predicate is `rdf:value` and object is `"class"`.

Internally — at the SPI level you were trying — you could have used `inMemModel.remove(Node.ANY, nodePredicate, nodeObject)`, which finds and deletes (using `delete`) matching triples. `delete` takes a ground triple and hence doesn't do a find.

`createAnon()` doesn't work simply because it's a different subject, so there is nothing to delete.

Comment: I have the other way around - i have `_:A68d23cacX3aX13f793fa898X3aXX2dX7ffd ` and I need to remove all its triples - how to do that ?

Comment: `model.removeAll(res, null, null)` (when res is your bnode). However you can also use `res.removeProperties()`, which does the same thing (assuming your resource is from that model).

Comment: The problem is that `ResourceFactory.createResource("_:A68d23cacX3aX13f793fa898X3aXX2dX7ffd")` and `A68d23cacX3aX13f793fa898X3aXX2dX7ffd` didnt work for me and `model.find(res,null,null)` was returning empty iterator. That was my main problem - how to match `bnode` as I would say it should match as mentioned.

Comment: Ah, I see. Try `Resource res = model.createResource(new AnonId("A68d23cacX3aX13f793fa898X3aXX2dX7ffd"));`

Comment: Interesting, I didnt try that one.Thanks in advance